# I can't access phpmyadmin with mamp

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, osx-snow-leopard, mamp

I have MAMP installed on my Mac Book Pro OS 10.6.8. The open start page on my MAMP is grayed out now. The Apache server button is green. The MySQL server button is red.

At one time I could access phpmyadmin. I have my php files in htdocs folder of MAMP that I can access in localhost:8888/filename.php. I want to create another database and table but I can't access phpmyadmin. I even downloaded phpmyadmin to my desktop but I don't know how to open it. Any suggestions

Comment: Is your MySQL port (preferences section of MAMP utility) 3306, Apache on 80?

Comment: my port is 8888 for Apache, and 8889 for MySQL

Comment: I tried localhost:8888/phpmyadmin. but that doesn't work.

Comment: I think I need to configure my phpmyadmin but I don't know how.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I often get MAMP giving me the red light for MySQL.

Every time I fixed it by quitting every instance of the `mysqld` process.

Check in Activity Monitor for multiple instances of that process running - if there are, then that is your problem. Quit them all, and restart MAMP.

Activity monitor can be found in `Applications > Utilities > Activity Monitor.app`. - Search for `mysqld` in the search box in the top right of activity monitor, and if there are multiple instances running, quit them all.

If not, try quitting the process anyway and restart MAMP.

**Update:** Easier way to perform this:

```
$ killall mysqld
```

From terminal.

Comment: Do you mean quit MAMP? Because I do that everytime. I stop working on a php file. Or what do you mean by quitting the process. Where is the activity monitor? :).

Comment: I found the activity monitor, found mysqld, double clicked on it and then I quit all processes. Then I restared MAMP. Now the phpmyadmin page comes up and I can access phymyadmin. Thanks a lot, everybody.

Comment: Just FYI for anyone who's looking, this also applies to MAMP PRO

Answer (score 35):

On the latest version of MAMP (4.1.1), the default option in the settings was set to "PHP 7.1.1". After I set the default option to 7.0.15, the PHPmyAdmin tools were no longer grayed and worked fine.

[image: Screenshot of PHP tab of MAMP preferences]

Comment: Thank you for chiming in Brent. I don't know how many times I saw that option but it just didn't "click" to try changing that. Once I did, the phpMyAdmin became lit!

Comment: I don't get how MAMP can be packed up with a PHPMyAdmin version that is incompatible with the bundled PHP version. But many thanks for this answer!

Comment: This worked for me after a completely new install of MAMP PRO 4 on MacOS. How weird this is the issue at all.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same or similar issue where PHPMyAdmin was greyed out after installing MAMP 3.5.  I checked the PHP version and it was set to 5.2, so I just bumped it up to 5.6 and the my PHPmyAdmin icon became active.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue after migrating my MAMP installation from one machine to another. The problem occurred due to permission issues on the MAMP directory.

To grant permission:

1. Locate the ***MAMP*** directory in ***Finder***
2. Ctrl-click > ***Get Info***
3. Under ***Sharing & Permissions***, if your username is not visible, click ***+*** and select your username
4. Ensure ***Privilege*** shows ***Read & Write***
5. Click ***Apply to enclosed items*** from the settings icon

Answer (score 0):

I had to go to the [Mamp website](https://www.mamp.info/en/)

and download the latest version then reinstall it to get things working again. This had the advantage of also giving me the cloud options and upgrading MySql but But you do have to remember your default directory and preferred ports if you want to use the ones that you had before. I hope this helps?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I was able to fix this was to reinstall MAMP Pro.